# Is there a single page listing privileges & their reputation requirements?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, privileges

On the old MathOverflow, there was a single page (the FAQ) which listed all the privileges and their reputation requirements, in increasing order. This has been replaced by the [Privileges page](https://mathoverflow.net/privileges/), which links to a separate page for each of the 25 individual privileges. This information is hard to digest, but wouldn't be hard to collate.

Is there a single page listing all the privileges and their reputation requirements? If not, could we please create one?

Comment: This is already under way, we're finishing off the implementation now - it will be integrated into the help center.

Comment: Note that hovering over the individual privileges gives you the actual reputation required, as well as a restatement of your percentage.

Answer (score 5):

[Here it is!](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges)